# Does a GCC compiler exist for the PIC32MZ series?

Tags: gcc, pic32

There is a GCC compiler for the `PIC32MX` series:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/README_c32_2_02.html

However, I can't find one for the `PIC32MZ` series. Does it exist?

Comment: Is it listed a target [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html)?  My understanding is that you could generate a cross-compiler for anything on that list.

Comment: That file hasn't been updated since 2011. There's a date at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The XC32 compiler series works for both MX and MZ parts. We use it.

Comment: I know, but we're looking for a GCC compiler. The reasons why would lead us too far here.

Comment: xc32 IS based on GCC... I don't see why it's not "gcc" enough.

Comment: If `xc32` is based on GCC, then how is it possible that Microchip claims rights on that software? They don't allow to redistribute `xc32` from other servers.

Comment: *shrug* but just saying. It's GCC based.

Answer (score 0):

As the PIC32 is a MIPS m4k architecture, I suppose a generic gcc MIPS cross compiler should work. Something like mipsel-elf-gcc.

One has to provide linker files, startup files, a C library (I suppose there is a newlib port), and some headers/drivers for the peripherals, a generic MIPS cross compiler should be able to generate code that can run on a PIC32.

Note this is my theoretical knowledge about the platform. I never build any code targetting PIC32 or any other MIPS based chip.